# Are absolutely continuous functions piece-wise monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was wondering whether absolutely continuous functions  $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are piecewise monotone.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please note that (despite appearances) this is a "question-and-answer" site, not a forum-based discussion site. The goal is to build a searchable "database" of well-posed math questions and answers, one question per page. That's why it's important to ask a separate question rather than a follow-up (and why a moderator is likely to relocate your follow-up if you don't do so yourself). I hope that's helpful, and again, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 5):

No. Take $f(x) = x^3 \sin 1/x$ with $f(0) = 0$. The derivative exists almost everywhere and $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) dt$ which is equivalent to $f$ being absolutely continuous. But on any open interval of $0$ we have $f$ neither increasing or decreasing.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the derivative exists *everywhere*, and is even continuous.

Comment: If you use $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2} \sin(1/x)$ I think you could get an example that is $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

In fact there are absolutely continuous functions that are nowhere monotone.
 Enumerate the open subintervals of $[0,1]$ with rational endpoints as $(s_n, t_n)$, $n=1\ldots \infty$.  Inductively define sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ such that

1. Each is a "fat Cantor" subset of $(s_n, t_n)$: compact, nowhere dense but with nonzero Lebesgue measure.
2. $A_n$ and $B_n$ are disjoint from each other and from all $A_j$ and $B_j$ with $j < n$.

Now define 
$$f(x) = m \left( [0,x] \cap \bigcup_n A_n\right) - m \left([0,x] \cap \bigcup_n B_n \right) $$

This has the desired properties.